# SSL Server IP/port conflict

Tags: centos

I'm getting the following error out our httpd error_log.

How do I go about solving the conflict?

```
[Mon Oct 03 09:28:46 2011] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: atmail.webmail:443 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/zzz_atmail_vhost.conf:48) vs. horde.webmail:443 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/zzz_horde_vhost.conf:41)
[Mon Oct 03 09:28:46 2011] [warn] Init: SSL server IP/port conflict: WEBSITE1:443 (/var/www/vhosts/WEBSITE1/conf/httpd.include:12) vs. horde.webmail:443 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/zzz_horde_vhost.conf:41)
```

Answer (score 2):

This warnings comes up because you are using multiple SSL certificates on one IP: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_faq.html#vhosts

Solutions:

- add another IP to the server.
- enable TLS Extension Server Name Indication ([SNI](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI))

Answer (score 1):

As quanta has said, you've got multiple virtual sites configured to use the same port (443) on the same IP address.  You might benefit from reading the answers to [Can I run two different secure sites using the port 443 on the same server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/73162/can-i-run-two-different-secure-sites-using-the-port-443-on-the-same-server) ; getting more IP addresses for your server is a common and excellent solution, but it's not the only one.